# how to select children elements?

Tags: jquery

html

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <div class="three">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to select children element. I tried this.

```
$('.one').children('.three').css('color','#f00');
```

I know the .find() function, but want to know another method.

Comment: There are a plethora of methods to select child elements in jQuery. I'd suggest browsing the [API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) would be a better use of yours and everyone elses' time.

Comment: What is wrong with `find()`? Why do you need another way?

Comment: The correct way to do it is with `find()`. Period. `children()` traverses 1 level in the tree, `find()` traverses ALL levels. IE. use `find()`

Comment: Can use a *context selector*, if op is having personal problems with find. `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`. That also internally translates to `find()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could always change the selector to chain classes together:

```
$(".one .three").css("color", "#f00");
```

This will select any children of the `.one` class which have the class `.three`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
$('.one > .two').children('.three').css('color','#f00');
```

Or of course:

```
$('.one > .two > .three').css('color','#f00');
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3nhrh/1/

Comment: please read the question before posting

Comment: @musefan Fair enough :) Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Below method may be help you :

```
var children=$('.one').children();

children.each(function(idx, val){
   $(this).css('color','#f00');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/CxuRZ/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try one of these lines** :

```
$('.one').children().children('.three').css('color','#f00');
$('.one').children('.two').children('.three').css('color','#f00');
$('.one').children('.two').find('.three').css('color','#f00');
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context selector:

```
$('.three', $('#one')).css(.....
```

Comment: This is wrong..... `,`  should not be there

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.one > div.three').css('color','#f00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nhrh/2/)

```
$("div").children(".two").css("color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

If the item with the class "three" exists only once in your document (or want to get all of them) you can just use `$('.three')`.

if you are looking for any "three" that is a descendant or a "two" that is a descendant of a "one"  use `$('.one .two .three')`

if you want the same only where they are direct children you can use  `$('.one > .two > .three')`

if you happen to have already a jquery object for the "one" node you can limit your previous searches like this: 
`$('.three' , theOne)` , `$(' .two .three' , theOne)` or  `$(' > .two > .three', theOne)`

I hope one of those meets your needs, If not then you should better clarify what exactly is the case.

Comment: The last one is what I'm looking

Comment: last being `$(' > .two > .three', theOne)` ?

Comment: $('.three', theOne)  Could you show me a demo taking html of mine?

Comment: this will find any "three" node that is a decendant of theOne.

Comment: here is a fiddler showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/epeleg/yEH94/

Comment: note however that using find is faster performance wise. (last I read aout it it was said to be around 10% faster on some test they did.